# su not working inside arch-chroot with dash shell

Tags: arch-linux, chroot, su, dash

When i try to do the following inside a dash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/dash

arch-chroot /mnt /bin/dash <<- EOF
    su myuser
    whoami
EOF
```

It simply logs the "root", but when i try to do it manually, it works fine:

```
$ arch-chroot /mnt
$ su myuser
$ whoami
> myuser
```

Any clues of what might be happening? probably some undocumented pitfall of dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with:

```
arch-chroot /mnt su myuser <<- EOF
    whoami
EOF
```